# Using Doctrine entity manager clear() method only for certain entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am currently using batch processing for inserting 100-200 entities at a time because of an external requests(I mean outside of my API). The problem is that I have to manage and mostly remove duplicates from those batches of entities before I call the `EntityManger#flush()`.

I have working code, however I use the `EntityManager#detach()` method, which accepts the object as a parameter and **is deprecated**. I can't use `EntityManger#clear()`, because it detaches all objects of a type, which is not the behavior I want the The question is if there is a way to detach a certain entity, which was already persisted with the `EntityManger#clear()`

Comment: From a practical point of view, no, there is no way to clear a specific entity without clearing everything.  Even using detach was always a bit problematical which is why it is being depreciated.  I don't quite understand your use case but in general you want the logic which avoids duplicates to occur before the entity is added to the manager.

Comment: @Cerad I do have logic to avoid duplicates, but it only would work like that if the request are done 1 by 1 but my problem is when we have 2 users making a request for the same resources and those two server requests are trying to create the same thing simultaneously.  I could persist them and immediately flush them but it's an enormous performance impact. Catching the exception and refreshing the entity manager is not an option also, so I am considering making a file, which would be constantly read and written. That also is making things slow but not so much

Comment: Yep it can be messy.  For myself I stopped trying to use the entity manager for bulk operations a long time ago.  I just drop down to sql, not only for performance reasons but to avoid all the entity manager pitfalls.

Comment: @Cerad Yeah using the entity manager for bigger operations is a pain, so I also as you have done dropped down to SQL just for those big bulk inserts and everything seems to be even faster :)

Answer (score 1):

All methods changing the unit of work temporarily, i.e. detaching/clearing a single entity, were deprecated for the next major release. The good news is, that detach as of now is un-deprecated, see [doctrine/orm #8466](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/8466)

> This PR also undeprecates EntityManager::detach for now, because unless we find some kind of replacement API it cannot be removed as relied on heavily by the batch processing use-cases with AbstractQuery::toIterable.

In other words, there probably is not a good replacement right now, which is why it will stay until one is found.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked the whole UnitOfWork class and did not found anything that would meet my needs, so I am just going to leave it like that with detach and when there is proper replacement, I might as well leave an answer with the newest method.